# How to force object's class when fetching it from API?

Tags: angular

I have an API that returns a bunch of conversations with a simple model:

```
export class ConversationVm {
   lastMessage: string;
   lastMessageDate: Date;
   buddyId: number;
   buddyUsername: string;
}
```

The fetching itself looks like this, where API returns JSON compliant to ConversationVm:

```
getConversations(): Observable<HttpResponse<ApiResponse<Array<ConversationVm>>>> {
   return this.client.get<Array<ConversationVm>>('api/conversation/get_conversations');
}
```

Underneath is the HttpClient of "@angular/common/http"

Now, when I make such call:

```
this.msgService.getConversations().subscribe(r => {
   console.log(typeof(r.body.data));
});
```

I expected the console to output Array<ConversationVm'>, but instead Array<Object'> is displayed.
It is problematic as properties of the Object are all strings instead of what they are defined by class.

Now, the questions are:

- How can I force that an object and its properties are exactly as defined in the class? Can it be parsed on the fly?
- Shouldn't Angular check whether an object returned from getConversations is of correct type (or try parsing it, as it's dynamic), instead of Object?

Comment: TypeScript **does not** (_cannot_, it doesn't exist at runtime) do any checking, casting or conversion of what you actually receive. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25401, and the updates https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using an interface instead of a class

```
export interface ConversationVm {
   lastMessage: string;
   lastMessageDate: Date;
   buddyId: number;
   buddyUsername: string;
}
```

And use the RXJS **map** operator to transform the data accordingly (if required)
If you want to use `typeof` you will have to truly create the instance of the class.
In order to do that, your class definition should have a constructor and then during the **map** you can instantiate the class.
I'll strongly discourage this, though.